# The reason of ripple on output of isolation amplifier

Tags: amplifier, adc, ripple

You can find schematic below. I have seen ripple (apapproximately 184mv) on output of isolation amplifier so I can not read output voltage of amplifier on my ADC.

What is the purpose of ripple on output of isolation amplifier? Do you have any advice for it?

By the way, I added 1k resistor to schematic. It's for high voltage. This situation has no effect on the problem.

You can find datasheet of **AMC1301** in here: http://www.ti.com/product/AMC1301

[image: Schematic]

Comment: What are resistors R and Ry46 in parallel for?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič It's about high voltage. You can find information about that on datasheet of AMC1301 (page 23)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have seen ripple (apapproximately 184mv) on output of isolation
>   amplifier so I can not read output voltage of amplifier on my ADC.

If the voltage input of the isolation amplifier has differential ripple then this will be seen at the output.

Alternatively, if the input has a common-mode voltage ripple (affecting Vin+ and Vin- equally) then you might see this on the output Vout+ and Vout- equally however, you are not using Vout- in your circuit so you cannot subtract the ripple from the signal. It is recommended that you use a differential measurement on the output of this isolation amplifier. Read the data sheet; it shows that the isolation barrier is likely performed by capacitors and these will pass common-mode AC frequencies through to the output: -

[image]

All the recommended application circuits show a differential output connection like so: -

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your rapidly response. Can I solve this problem without differantial amplifier or new pcb design?

Comment: What frequency is the ripple? What frequency range is your wanted signal? How much DC error can you tolerate (a diff output will generally produce much smaller DC errors including drift against time)? You are not using it as recommended hence there could be other issues that this comment hasn't covered or considered.

Comment: I am currently measuring voltage maximum 200mV with R46. Can I get a useful result for ADC by increasing this value? For example, 2k resistors with 400mV, 5k resistors with 1V sense. Please check 7th page of datasheet. VINP = –250 mV to +250 mV . Is it answer of this question?

Comment: Yes, that forces you to stay within a range of +/-250 mV at the input.

Comment: When I am checking on TPAN2 I had see ripple. But when I am checking on input of C61 I did not see ripple. So I will remove the R40. What do you think about that? Is it possible?

Comment: I strongly recommend that you use the device as intended. I can only recommend solutions that I feel are covered by the data sheet. Removing R40 is something I am unable to comment on because I don't understand why it is present. If TPAN2 is a test point then removing R40 will be pointless.

Comment: When I'm checking VOUT(+) and VOUT(-) I have seen not reverse voltage signal wave. So I'm thinking differential amplifier can not solve this problem isn't it?

Comment: If you have differential ripple at the input then you'll get differential ripple at the output also. Sounds like you need better input filtering.